# Simple jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu with specific list item expanded on page load

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I am trying to figure out how to have a specific list item featured in a Simple jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu expanded on page load. I tried adding this to the jquery to open the first list item on load, however it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('#nav li:first ul').show();
```

The remainder of the jQuery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
$('#nav li:first ul').show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The development page [can be viewed here.](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/morocco.html)

Thankyou!

Comment: Don't use `$(this).attr('class') != 'active'` use `$(this).hasClass('active')`. This will prevent any issues with spaces in the class or if there's another class, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything wrapped in the `.click()` function. You're saying you want it to open on page load, but none of that code is executed until a nav item is actually clicked.

Maybe all you have to do is add a `$('#nav > li > a.active').next().show();` (I am assuming the nav item that opens has the `active` class there on page load (i.e. it's put there via PHP or something).

Also, as per my comment, don't use `$(this).attr('class') != 'active'` use instead `$(this).hasClass('active')`. This will prevent any issues with spaces in the class or if there's another class, etc.

Comment: Using $(this).attr('class') != 'active' appears to break the drop down funntionality. Also, there is no active class attached to the Nav item. I was just wondering if there was a way that I could have a list item expanded on page load.

Comment: Yes, if it has the class active, you can use the method I outlined. Otherwise, if you want it to be indexed based, you can do `$('#nav > li > a').eq(index).next().show();` where `index` is the item you want to open (a number).

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for something like :

open up "Ghana" as its the first link ?

```
$(function(){$($('a','#nav')[0]).click();});
```

Comment: Yeah, so when the page is opened the 'Ghana' panel is expanded revealing the sub menu. That didn't appear to work when I added it to the jQuery: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
$(function(){$($('a','#nav')[0]).click();});
    }
  });
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not a jQuery Accordion, but rather [an accordion plugin from Adobe](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/data_api/apis/accordion.html).  The link in the previous sentence shows the API and it looks like you want to use something like:

```
Accordion1.openPanel(index);
```

I tried this using the Chrome dev tools and it didn't work, so you might want to make sure you have your markup correct.  I don't have a ton of time to look into this, but hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies, there are actually 2 accordions on the page. The one I'm referring to is the expandable vertical navigation down the left side.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `$('#nav li:first ul').show();` needs to be kept separate from the rest of the jquery script.